# Importing (bad) CSV-data into Excel

Tags: excel, vba, csv

I'm trying to import some (bad) CSV-data into Excel.
I call it bad because it has hardcoded enters in some cells, and other cells which contain numbers formatted as text (with a prefix 0 which I need)

I have created two importmacros:

```
Sub LoadSheetCSV(fromsheet As String, sheetname As String)    

'Load sheet
fromfile = DownDatafiles & "\" & fromsheet & ".csv"

Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
ActiveSheet.Name = sheetname
Application.CutCopyMode = False     
 
 
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(filename:=fromfile, Local:=True)

aData = wb.Worksheets(1).UsedRange.Value
lRows = UBound(aData, 1)
lCols = UBound(aData, 2)

ThisWorkbook.Activate
Sheets(sheetname).Activate

With ActiveSheet
 .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(lRows, lCols)).Value = aData
End With

wb.Close        
     
End Sub
```

Unfortunately, this one removes the prefix zeroes from the numbers.

The next one keeps the prefixed zero, but leaves blank rows when it hits the hardcoded enters:

```
Sub LoadSheetCSV_ALT(fromsheet As String, sheetname As String, progresstxt As String)

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim colDataTypesArr(1 To 10000) As Long
Dim i As Long    
   
'Load sheet
fromfile = DownDatafiles & "\" & fromsheet & ".csv"

Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
ActiveSheet.Name = sheetname
Application.CutCopyMode = False


Set ws = ActiveSheet
For i = 1 To UBound(colDataTypesArr)
    colDataTypesArr(i) = 2
Next i

With ws.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & fromfile, Destination:=ws.Range("A1"))
     .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
     .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = True
     .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
     .TextFileColumnDataTypes = colDataTypesArr
     .TextFilePlatform = 65001
     .Refresh
End With

End sub
```

Any idea how I can merge both solutions to one good one? :-)

Thanks!

Comment: CSV files do not have cells as an Excel sheet does. Please provide some example data.

Comment: A file like this should load fine if you use PowerQuery (Data >> From Text/csv) - it will allow you to set columns containing leading zeros as Text, and preserve line breaks in "cells" as long as those values are quoted in the file.